# mouse coordinates with round numbers only - jquery function

Tags: function, coordinates, coordinate-transformation, jquery

```
$('.ccc').mousemove(function (e) {
        $('.ddd').text(" " + (e.pageX - $(this).offset().left - 0.5) + ", " + (e.pageY - $(this).offset().top) + " ");
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n8rna/9/

The problem with this function is that Firefox and Opera calculates the div borders slightly different, so I have a difference of 0.5 (in X direction) in these browsers.

So how can I have round numbers only in this function?

I guess rounding up the numbers would be the most simple solution for this, but I am also open for other approaches.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n8rna/11/

Answer (score 2):

Use the round function:

```
Math.round(2.3): // Equal to 2
```

If It's FF and Chrome causing you problems, you may need to check the user agents before you do the rounding. However, this seems like something that could be solved in another, less hacky, way.

Comment: sorry for being such a noob, but can you edit the fiddle for me? I can't get this to work.

Comment: I don't do others' work. What are you having trouble with? I'll help, but I won't do.